# mysql pivot table syntax error

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

mysql says I have a syntax error on this code. can anyone tell me where it is?

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN uploaddate = ''', uploaddate,
''' THEN points END) `', uploaddate, '`'))
INTO @sql
FROM prepress.imsexport;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT uploadedby, ', @sql, ' 
FROM prepress.imsexport 
GROUP BY uploadedby');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I also want to use date_format on uploaddate how do I do that without screwing up the concat function?

Comment: Post the exact error message and the exact table schema `SHOW CREATE TABLE imsexport;`

Comment: What data type is `uploaddate` is of (date, datetime, timestamp, int)? Do you always have one row for `uploaded` by per `uploaddate`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE imsexport
 (`id` int, `uploadedby` varchar(255), `uploaddate` varchar(255), `points` int(11))
;
 
INSERT INTO imsexport
 (`id`, `uploadedby`, `uploaddate`, `points`)
VALUES
 (1, 'Bob', '2013-01-01 12:30:00', '1'),
 (2, 'Bob', '2013-01-02 06:05:00', '2'),
 (3, 'Bob', '2013-01-03 14:25:00', '1'),
 (4, 'Bob', '2013-01-04 15:30:00', '3'),
 (5, 'Sue', '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '1'),
 (6, 'Sue', '2013-01-01 00:45:00', '3'),
 (7, 'Sue', '2013-01-02 16:20:00', '2'),
 (8, 'Sue', '2013-01-04 17:10:00', '2')
;

Comment: Error

SQL query:

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM imsexport
GROUP BY uploadedby' at line 2 ----->this is the mysql error

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `upload date` is of type `VARCHAR` and not `DATETIME`? What client tool are you using to execute this code?

Answer (score 0):

> *mysql says I have a syntax error on this code. Can anyone tell me where it is?*

At first glance your code looks fine.

> *I also want to use date_format on uploaddate how do I do that without screwing up the concat function?*

You most likely meant to use `SUM()` instead of `MAX()` if there might be multiple rows per `uploadedby` per date.

Here is how your code with `DATE_FORMAT()` might look like

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(uploaddate) = ''', DATE(uploaddate),
''' THEN points END) `', DATE_FORMAT(uploaddate, '%m/%d/%Y'), '`'))
INTO @sql
FROM imsexport;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT uploadedby, ', @sql, ' 
FROM imsexport 
GROUP BY uploadedby');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| UPLOADEDBY | 01/01/2013 | 01/02/2013 | 01/03/2013 | 01/04/2013 |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|        Bob |          1 |          2 |          1 |          3 |
|        Sue |          4 |          2 |     (null) |          2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e8c/2)** demo

---

Here is how it will look like being executed using mysql console

```
mysql> SET @sql = NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    -> CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(uploaddate) = ''', DATE(uploaddate),
    -> ''' THEN points END) `', DATE_FORMAT(uploaddate, '%m/%d/%Y'), '`'))
    -> INTO @sql
    -> FROM imsexport;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT uploadedby, ', @sql, ' 
    '> FROM imsexport 
    '> GROUP BY uploadedby');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| uploadedby | 01/01/2013 | 01/02/2013 | 01/03/2013 | 01/04/2013 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Bob        |          1 |          2 |          1 |          3 |
| Sue        |          4 |          2 |       NULL |          2 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20
FROM imsexport
GROUP BY uploadedby' at line 1 ----> now this is the error that is showing up

Comment: Comment out three statements starting with `PREPARE` and use this one instead `SELECT @sql;` and post the result.

Comment: Did you look at the working sqlfiddle example I provided based on your sample data?

Comment: I did that is why I'm confused why it is not working when I apply it on my table.

Comment: Most likely you have some garbage in your `uploaddate` column. I asked you to post the result of `SELECT @sql;` It will show the problem. And you still didn't answer how do you execute this code (mysql cli, phpmyadmin, client code, what exactly?)

Comment: I deleted all three statements starting from PREPARE and replaced it with SELECT '@sql;'. There are no more errors but the table is just 2 rows '@sql' as the header and [BLOB - 1.1KiB] as the second row. What do you mean by post the result?

Comment: The contents of this blob is your query. Post it here or on some site and post a link here. Or execute it in mysql client and just copy paste the result. Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e8c/3) example for you. As you can see the result is the generated query.

Comment: SELECT `@sql`
FROM `imsexport`
WHERE ;

MySQL said: Documentation
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). --> this is the post result. I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: You're doing something wrong. There is no in my answer or in the example `SELECT @sql` along with `FROM imsexport` together. It looks like you put quotes around `@sql` in `CONCAT`.

Comment: Now can you just open mysql console (command line interface) copy and paste the code I provided in the answer exactly as it is and execute it by hitting `Enter`? See updated answer it shows the exact results being executed from mysql console.

Comment: Did it help after all?